# Update records with sequential number number based on date field

Tags: mysql

I have a database full of about 500 records that work in the following way

```
id | group | date | team1 | team2
```

I want to add a new field "matchid", and fill it in with a number 1 - 8 per group. So the record set would look like

```
1 | 2 | 2014-03-09 15:00:00 | j1 | j2       
2 | 2 | 2014-03-09 16:30:00 | j3 | j4  
3 | 2 | 2014-03-10 15:00:00 | j5 | j6  
4 | 2 | 2014-03-10 16:30:00 | j7 | j8  
5 | 2 | 2014-03-11 15:00:00 | j9 | j10  
6 | 2 | 2014-03-11 16:30:00 | j11 | j12  
7 | 2 | 2014-03-12 15:00:00 | j13 | j14  
8 | 2 | 2014-03-12 16:30:00 | j15 | j16  
9 | 3 | 2014-03-13 15:00:00 | j1 | j2  
10 | 3 | 2014-03-14 16:30:00 | j3 | j4  
11 | 3 | 2014-03-15 15:00:00 | j5 | j6  
12 | 3 | 2014-03-16 16:30:00 | j7 | j8  
13 | 3 | 2014-03-17 15:00:00 | j9 | j10  
14 | 3 | 2014-03-18 16:30:00 | j11 | j12  
15 | 3 | 2014-03-19 15:00:00 | j13 | j14  
16 | 3 | 2014-03-20 16:30:00 | j15 | j16
```

This then goes on and on, so this happens weekly, groups get together on sequential times, usually 2 groups per day, so think of this as like a round like in sporting events.

What I need to do is get the new ID which will be something like

```
01
02
..
```

and so on to `08`.

What I need to do is look at the date for the group and rank everything in order then update the matchid field with the sequential number.

The reason this needs to be done is that the managers have added a new matchid which relates to the game per match per group.

I am looking for a way to programatically do this within SQL so that I dont have to manually update every record.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this programatically in PHP and mysql.

I itereated through each "group" and tested the date values to order them into an array. once i had them ordered my date in the array, I was able to easily add the numbers sequentially.